# How can i tell if there is a path between all vertices using recursive Depth First Search algorithm?

Tags: graph, depth-first-search

I'm trying to tell if a graph is strongly connected or not. To qualify as strongly connected, a graph should have the following properties:
1) DFS algorithm will declare that all nodes are reachable from Starting Vertex
2) When all the directions of edges are reversed(transpose graph) all nodes are reachable from Starting Vertex.

Here is my DFS implementation:

```
 public void dfs(String startName) {
        Vertex v = getVertex(startName);
        v.dist = 0;
        dfsVertex(v);
    }

 List<Vertex> wasVisited;
 List<Edge> wasVisitedEdge;

    private void dfsVertex(Vertex v) {

        wasVisited.add(v);

        for(Edge e: v.adj){

            if(!wasVisitedEdge.contains(e)){

                Vertex w = e.dest;

                if(!wasVisited.contains(w)){

                    wasVisitedEdge.add(e);
                    w.prev = v;
                    wasVisited.add(w);
                    w.dist = v.dist + 1;
                    dfsVertex(w);
                }
            }



        }

    }
```

How can i tell if there is a path between every vertices using the above algorithm?

Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 0):

So your goal is to check to see if a graph is strongly connected. This helps because then you can simply assume you are given an arbitrary node. What your algorithm does is take each node that is adjacent to the queried node via the connecting edges

```
for(Edge e: v.adj)
```

check if it has been searched

```
if(!wasVisitedEdge.contains(e)) AND if(!wasVisited.contains(w))
```

add it to the list if it hasn't been searched

```
wasVisitedEdge.add(e); AND wasVisited.add(w);
```

mark information about how the newly seen node was reached

```
w.prev = v; AND w.dist = v.dist + 1;
```

and then use those adjacent nodes to search for "new" nodes.

```
dfsVertex(w);
```

However, there is a bug in your algorithm. Notice that you called:

```
wasVisited.add()
```

twice. once for "v" and once for "w". The problem with this is that "w" becomes the "v" for the next query and hence after the first call with the original root (or starting) node, you'll retain duplicates of every other node in the list

```
wasVisited
```

The simple fix is to completely remove the line

```
wasVisited.add(w);
```

and then the code will work properly. After the code executes

```
wasVisited
```

will contain each node that could be reached from the original queried root node. From here you can simply check to see if each node in the graph is stored in the list. If each node is accounted for, then the list is strongly connected. Otherwise it is not strongly connected. This algorithm should also work regardless of whether the graph is directed or undirected.